# Sort the product collection before load by attribute option in Magento2

Tags: magento2, product-attribute, catalogsearch, sorting

I am trying to sort the Product collection based on the attribute option value,

I used below plugin

**Vendor/Module/di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
   <type name="Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer">
       <plugin name="custom_product_model_layer" type="Vednor\Module\Plugin\Layer" />
    </type>
</config>
```

Then in **Vendor/Module/Plugin/Layer.php**

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin;

class Layer
{
    private $logger;

    public function __construct(
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger
    ) {
        $this->logger = $logger;
    }

    public function aroundGetProductCollection(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer $subject,
        \Closure $proceed
    ) {

        $result = $proceed();
        $result->addAttributeToSort('brand', 'puma');

        return $result;
    }
}
```

**Second Method:**

**di.xml**

```
<type name="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar">
    <plugin name="custom_product_toolbar" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\Toolbar" />
</type>
```

**Then Vendor/Module/Plugin/Toolbar.php**

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin;

class Toolbar
{

    protected $_objectManager;
    protected $request;
    private $logger;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectmanager,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $request,
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger
    ) {
        $this->_objectManager = $objectmanager;
        $this->request        = $request;
        $this->logger         = $logger;
    }

    public function aroundSetCollection(
        \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar $subject,
        \Closure $proceed,
        $request
    ) {
        $result = $proceed($request);

        $this->_collection = $request;
        $currentOrder      = $subject->getCurrentOrder();
        $category          = $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')->registry('current_category');
        if ($category) {
            $page = $this->request->getParam('p');
            if ($page == '') {
                $page = 1;
            }
            $this->_collection->getCurPage();
            $this->_collection->setCurPage($page);
        }
        if ($currentOrder) {
            if ($currentOrder == 'relevance') {
                // Suggest me the logic here
            }
        }

        return $result;
    }
}
```

I have created a attribute called **"brand"** so whenever the product is searched, I need to load the products on top which are set as **"puma"** option for that particular attribute.

I am trying with Both methods, but both are not working, can I get any help on this. Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't sort by attribute options value. You can sort by `asc` or `desc` by attirbute using **addAttributeToSort()**.

This is core issue generated in github. You can get reference about that by this below link :

> https://github.com/Smile-SA/elasticsuite/issues/450

If you want to sort by attribute name then, you can use after plugin method instead of around and modify your collection :

Create **di.xml** file and add plugin and add this below code :

> app/code/RH/AfterPlugin/etc/frontend/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<type name="Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer">
    <plugin name="rh_afterplugin_model_layer" type="RH\AfterPluginCode\Plugin\SortCollection" sortOrder="3"  />
</type>
</config>
```

Create **SortCollection.php** plugin file and add this below code :

> app/code/RH/AfterPlugin/Plugin/SortCollection.php

```
<?php

/**
  * Copyright 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
  * See COPYING.txt for license details.
  */

namespace RH\AfterPluginCode\Plugin;

class SortCollection {

    public function afterGetProductCollection(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer $subject, $result) {
        $result->addAttributeToSort('brand','ASC'); //DESC for descending.
        //$result->addAttributeToSort('sku');
        //$result->setOrder('brand','ASC'); For dropdown type attribute you can use this.
        return $result;
    }
}
```

Comment: hi @Rohan, Thanks for your answer, I've removed all my code and tried your answer, getting this exception, "You cannot define a correlation name 'brand_t1' more than once"

Comment: brand_t1 is attribute options?

Comment: No, "brand" is the attribute_code, once the plugin code added, getting that error

Comment: Then, can you pls tell me what is brand_t1?

Comment: There is no "brand_t1" attribute or option, only i have created "brand" attribute ,when try to sort with plugin code, getting this error, As per my research on that, someone suggested that, same attribute_code is already sorted but we are trying to sort it again, Actually I'm not sorted that anywhere

Comment: check my updated answer.

Comment: yes @Rohan, Thank you, its working now, if any suggestions for sorting particular option on top, you can update, Thanks!!

Comment: Yes sure. Happy to help :)